# Запятая между определениями-прилагательными

Tags: пунктуация, прилагательные, определения

В словосочетании "несчастный седой человек" запятая же не ставится, так как прилагательные характеризуют его с разных сторон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном вами фрагменте запятая между прилагательными не нужны, так как они разнородны (характеризуют с разных сторон).

Подробнее: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114.